# Why does function overload resolution in C++ consider non-static member functions for static calls?

Tags: c++

I was wondering why function overload resolution in C++ does consider non-static member functions when calling a static method.

I have read the documentation [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) and it states that

> If any candidate function is a member function (static or non-static), but not a constructor, it is treated as if it has an extra parameter (implicit object parameter) which represents the object for which they are called and appears before the first of the actual parameters.

So consider the following code.

```
struct A {
   static void foo(int a, float b){...}
   void foo(float a, int b){...}
};
```

Then the call `A::foo(1.f, 1.f)` is ambiguous.

Static member functions are considered for overload resolution of non-static function calls, which makes sense.

```
A a;
a.foo(1, 1.f); //can safely call static method
```

But why is it also done the other way around (considering non-static member functions when calling a function with `Class::function`)? Why can't the compiler simply choose `static void foo(int a, float b)`?

Comment: I'm 90% certain `A` is ill-formed.

Comment: How do you mean? It should compile fine without the ambiguous call.

Comment: Mmm... You are correct. I mistook your example as having the exact same parameter types (it's the end of day for me). Apologies, `A` isn't ill-formed.

Comment: You can call non-static members with the `class::` syntax. The compiler cannot know - from that syntax alone - whether you are calling a static or non-static function.

Comment: You are right! I don't understand why I get so many downvotes though. It might be a stupid question for experienced C++ developers, but not extremely obvious if you don't think about inheritance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why can't the compiler simply choose `static void foo(int a, float b)`?

My understanding of your questions is that you assume the syntax `A::foo` is unambiguous due to the non-instance `A::` prefix. But have a look at this scenario:

```
struct A {
   static void foo(int, float);
   void foo(float, int);
};

struct B : A {
   // Hide the base class foo
   void foo()
   {
      // Now explicitly call it... this is ambiguous!
      A::foo(1.f, 1.f);
   }
};
```

Hence, the `A::` prefix can refer to both `static` and non-`static` member functions, depending on the context. The compiler can't assume that it's referring to a `static` member function only.

There are more scenarios where a qualified non-`static` member function call like `A::foo` is necessary, e.g. in a diamond inheritance structure (if you don't use `virtual` inheritance). This is why any member function *can* be invoked like this (even when it's unnecessary and doesn't make sense: `A a; a.A::foo(1, 2.f);`.